How can the antichrist be left alone, and fight with a great army at the same time?
Reading from the book of Daniel Chapter 11, there is a man mentioned near the end of the chapter that most agree is the anti-christ.
Daniel describes his eventual end as him being pressed by several kings and eventually his army abandons him:

Daniel 11
44 However, news from the east and north will frighten him, so that he moves out in great fury to ruin and completely do away with many. 45 Finally, when he pitches the tents of his palace between the seas and the mountain of the holy Glory, he will come to his end, with no one to help him.

However the book of Revelation describes the end of the anti-christ as a battle between his armies and Heavens armies:

Revelation 19:19
I saw the beast and the kings of the earth and their armies gathered together to do battle with the rider of the horse and his army.

Is the book of Daniel suggesting that the Antichrist is basically a "weak" version of himself by the time Jesus arrives, and it's the other kings of the earth that are primarily waging war against Jesus?
If that is true what can we make of Revelation 13 that says:

The whole world was filled with wonder and followed the beast.

Daniel mentions the other kings eating at a table with the anti-christ, would they not have his number/mark on them during this time?

Daniel 11
27 These two kings, bent on mischief, will sit at the same table, speaking lies to each other; but none of this will succeed; because the appointed end will not have come yet. 28 Then the king of the north will return to his own land with great wealth; with his heart set against the holy covenant, he will take action and then return home.


Hi there and welcome to C.SE. Great question. Since it seems to be a solely biblical question, I recommend going to https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/ in the future. They are more focused on questions like: "What does this or that mean in the Bible?"

Hi! You may want to limit the scope of this question to a particular denomination or school of thought - I think there are many Christians who do not believe Daniel 11 is about the antichrist at all!

I suggest this question is based partly on a misunderstanding. You are taking "left alone" way too literally, because all those tents of v45 are presumably not empty. Surely Daniel means only that he had no royal allies left.

Daniel chapter 11 is an historical account of the events involving Darius the Mede and various kings who appear in Persia.  The mighty king (verse 3) is Alexander the Great [336-323].  Events culminate in 168 B.C. when Antiochus Epiphanes desecrates the temple in Jerusalem.  In December 165 the altar of the temple was rededicated.
Daniel 11:35 refers to “the time of the end” which will “come at the appointed time”.  My NIV Study Bible notes make this comment:

From here [verse 36] to the end of chapter 11 the antichrist is in view.  The details of this section do not fit what is known of Antiochus Epiphanes.

“At the time of the end” (verses 40 to 45) the King of the South engages the King of the North in battle but “he will come to his end, and no-one will help him.”  This may be a reference to the future battle of Armageddon.  Chapter 12 of Daniel links to Revelation chapter 16.
The events pertaining to the End Times, or the Day of the Lord, or the Second Coming of Christ Jesus, and Armageddon are still future.  The End Time antichrist has not yet been revealed.
Revelation is an allegory of the current reality of how Satan influences and manipulates governments and religions.  Only when the Antichrist is identified, purporting to be the returned Christ Jesus, and all the nations bow down and worship him, looking to him as the saviour of the world, will Satan have realised his goal, which is to demand the worship that rightfully belongs to Christ Jesus.  Then Christ Jesus returns, accompanied by all the heavenly hosts, and destroys His enemies.
Your question is unanswerable because the events in Daniel chapter 11 were fulfilled over 2,000 years ago.  Revelation 19 is a future event, culminating in the battle of Armageddon.
Edit: Bear in mind there are two allegorical beasts described in Revelation (the beast from the sea and the beast from the earth) as well as “the image of the beast”.  This question and answers may be useful: What is the current Reformed and Protestant view of the 'image of the beast' (Revelation 13: 14 &15)?


1  ... I appreciate your recognition that much of the chapter deals with the period leading up to the rise of Antiochus Epiphanes. But I think 44-50 refer roughly to the Maccabean period rather than thousands of years in the future.


@DanFefferman - Did you mean Daniel 11:40-45?  I haven't got a verse 50!

Yes thanks for the correction.

If you are interested in the book of Daniel as a whole regarding these kind of questions then Edward B. Pusey's commentary is very excellent (consisting of nine lectures). Generally, to understand the Book of Daniel it is vital to get a knowledge of the history the book is refering to: the more knowledge the better. Edward Young gives the historical background for Daniel chapter 11, but leads astray on Daniel 9:24-27. ( For that I recommend "Daniel's 70 weeks" by Pastor Derek Walker. Also needed is "Babylonian Chronology - 626 bc to ad 75" by Richard A. Parker and Waldo Dubberstein, which is free online: this is often accepted as the number 1 authority on the reign lengths and their dates and New Moon dates for the era, though in rare instances the (free) online tables of astronomer Rita Gautschy differ by a day on New Moons, and take precedence in my opinion (See websites "The Jewish Calendar" and "Last and First Sightings of Lunar Crescent" by Rita Gautschy).
As has been already said, Daniel 11 first refers to Antiochus Epiphanes as a type of the coming anti-Christ. It then seamlessly morphs into speaking of the anti-Christ (AC) himself.
V36 does not apply to Antiochus Epiphanes (AE).. the fact is he worshipped false gods very greatly, with very generous offerings.  So by v36 it is no longer talking about AE.
Before v36 it is probably all about AE.. It is difficult to know precisely where talk of AE ends /talk of AC begins.
The "king of the North" is not just one individual: it refers to many of the kings of the Seleucid Empire, one of whom was AE.  Likewise the "King of the South" is referring to a number of the Ptolemite Kings of Egypt.
In verse 30 the "ships of Chittim" refers back to a prophecy of Baalam in Numbers 24:24, and means ships from Rome.. Chittim does not only mean Cyprus, it means descendants of Kittim, Gen 10:4, and can mean anyone from the  Mediterranean region, including Italy or Greece.  This section probably also refers to AE.
Your assumption Daniel 11:27-28 is referring to the AC is not according to Pusey's view, is very likely incorrect, making the question difficult to answer.

Part of the confusion here is caused by thinking that the Antichrist and the Beast are the same person.
There may also be some confusion between the partial fulfilment over 2000 years ago, and the final fulfilment just before the Day of the Lord, Christ's return, and the beginning of the Government of God during the Millennium.
In the book of Revelation:

the Beast is a great political and military power, a union of ten nations led by the King of the North.
the Harlot is a great religious power, lead by the False Prophet, who is Antichrist.

The Woman uses (rides) the Beast (political and military leader) to obtain even greater power, but eventually the Beast turns and destroys her (the Church and Antichrist).
Reread the prophecies with these definitions in mind.
